# file_get_contents reads data partially

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using `file_get_contents('php://input')` to read data send over the line. Sometimes, the data stored in `$jsonString` is trimmed as if `file_get_contents` failed to read it to completion. I am wondering, what are possible reasons for `file_get_contents` to only read data partially? The data itself is user generated, and is therefore difficult to repeat the problem in controlled environment.

code:

```
public static function VerifyTopLevelJson(array $params){
    if( strpos($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"], "application/json") === -1 ){
        Errors::sendJson(400, "not json");
    }

    $jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json = json_decode($jsonString);

    foreach ($params as $param){
        if (!isset($json->$param)){
            self::StoreMissingError($param, $jsonString);
            Errors::sendJson(400, "missing: ".$param);
        }
    }
    return $json;
}
```

// Errors::sendJson() function

```
public static function sendJson(int $statusCode, $jsonObject=null){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    http_response_code($statusCode);
    echo json_encode($jsonObject);
    die();

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `strpos(...) === false` instead of `-1`?

Answer (score 2):

Is the input very large? What *exactly* have you observed?  Are you sure it's just not malformed json or are you actually able to dump `$JsonString` to reproduce the error? If you can't consistently reproduce the problem it's going to be hard to get answers.

That said, the primary factors I would start with are the php.ini directives (in this order) which affect the size of data you can post to your webserver:

1. [max_input_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)
2. [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)
3. [upload_max_filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)
4. [memory_limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

When it comes to truncated data from a post request, 9 times out of 10 it's either `max_input_vars` or `post_max_size`.

Comment: I am storing `$jsonString` into mariadb LONGTEXT column so I am able to see the truncated json. The input is large (~40kB), but a majority of requests with even bigger input (70kB) work as expected. This is an example of input: `{"json_param_1":"value_1","json_param_2":"<!DOCTYPE html>...removedAlmostEverythingForClarity\\\",\\\"connected\\\":t`. Note how it randomly cuts it. On client side, the json is generated using `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Larger requests can still be truncated if they contain more vars. Could that be the case?  What are the values of those directives I mentioned above? I've also seen this happen with a VPN where the connection was intermittent.

Comment: `max_input_vars = 1000, post_max_size = 100M, upload_max_filesize = 100M, memory_limit = 256M`

Comment: 1000 is pretty low for `max_input_vars`.  Even if that isn't what's going on here, you're likely to encounter issues with a setting that low. I've seen more than a few forms that submit upwards of 10,000 values.

Comment: But since you seem to be submitting s single value as one large string, my guess is it's unrelated to max_input_vars.  How are your clients connecting?  Ultimately, you'll need to be able to reliably reproduce this issue to solve it - and of course validate the input to make sure you're not parsing truncated data. If it's an ajax request, make sure to send back a warning to the client letting them know there was an issue.

Comment: I was hoping this is a php issue.  In essence, js ajax request sends info to the c# server. c# uses httpclient to forward it to php server. Now I'll inspect client request timeouting or maybe the proxy between the client and the server is timeouting